# Start module before boot

Tags: boot, kernel-modules, initramfs, yocto

Is there a way to start a module (framebuffer display driver, `fbtft_device`) before boot so that it can be used for boot-time splash screen? Its like issuing a `modprobe` command before boot. I want to do this in order to activate my display device and move the splash screen to framebuffer that it is connected to.

I have been reading about this and stumpled upon "`initramfs`", which allows you to use an image from RAM at boot time. However what I want to achieve is to just fire up a module before boot-time. I am not sure if "`initramfs`" is exactly what I'm looking for.

I am using Yocto-based embedded Linux distribution and want to know if I can use something like "`initramfs`" to achieve what I want to do. If so, I'd like to ask some questions:

- Do I include a duplicate of my original image/distro there? Or just a plain image with the module in it?
- How do I specify how to handle this boot process?
- How do I modify `/etc/initramfs-tools` in Yocto?

Any pointers/links/thoughts would help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you build the driver into your kernel, rather than as a module?

Comment: fbtft is a driver from staging directory from Linux kernel. I am not so experienced with building it into the kernel. But I assume it is already like that. I dont build a module with `.ko` extension. In other words, when I compile my Yocto image (I dont do anything related to that driver), it is already available in the image. So I can call a simple command `modprobe fbtft_device .....` to fire up the display. What I want to do is to do this before boot.